# jooq TIMESTAMP(6) support

Tags: java, mariadb, jooq, java-time

I am trying to use Java Jooq library for inserting a timestamp with millisecond precision in a MariaDB table where I have a column of type TIMESTAMP(6).
The line of code, just as an example is:

```java
eventRecord.setEventtimestamp(LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(Instant.parse("2021-05-18T16:47:31.862750Z").getEpochSecond() , Instant.parse("2021-05-18T16:47:31.862750Z").getNano(), ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Unfortunately the result in MariaDB is truncated and no milliseconds are inserted:

```
2021-05-18 16:47:31.000000
```

The table structure is:

```
MariaDB [plc_data]> DESCRIBE events;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default          | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
| event_id            | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL             |       |
| eventTimestamp      | timestamp(6) | YES  |     | NULL             |       |
| insertTimestamp     | timestamp(6) | YES  |     | utc_timestamp(6) |       |
| machineSerialNumber | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL             |       |
| data_block          | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL             |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+------------------+-------+
```

And the generated code for the two timestamp fields:

```java
    /**
     * The column <code>plc_data.events.eventTimestamp</code>. GMT
     */
    public final TableField<EventsRecord, Instant> EVENTTIMESTAMP = createField(DSL.name("eventTimestamp"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME.defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("NULL", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME)), this, "GMT", new TimestampConverter());

    /**
     * The column <code>plc_data.events.insertTimestamp</code>. GMT
     */
    public final TableField<EventsRecord, Instant> INSERTTIMESTAMP = createField(DSL.name("insertTimestamp"), org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME.defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("utc_timestamp(6)", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME)), this, "GMT", new TimestampConverter());
```

The `TimestampConverter` class you could see in the generated code is a custom converter I wrote:

```java
 * Jooq converter to use Instant instead of SQL TIMESTAMP which is mapped
 * into LocalDateTime
 */
public class TimestampConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Instant> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2866811348870878385L;

    /**
     * Convert from {@code LocalDateTime} to {@code Instant}
     */
    @Override
    public Instant from(LocalDateTime databaseObject) {
        return databaseObject.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
    }

    /**
     * Convert from {@code Instant} to {@code Timestamp}
     */
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime to(Instant userObject) {
        return userObject.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Return the from Type Class (Database Type Class)
     */
    @Override
    public Class<LocalDateTime> fromType() {
        return LocalDateTime.class;
    }

    /**
     * Return the to Type Class (User type Class)
     */
    @Override
    public Class<Instant> toType() {
        return Instant.class;
    }
}
```

Which is the way to instruct Jooq to insert the milliseconds part of my date ?

Regards,

S.

Comment: Your input strings passed to `Instant.parse` are invalid, lacking the `Z` needed to indicate an offset.

Comment: What's the DDL of your table, as well as the generated code? Do you really get a `TIMESTAMP(6)` data type, or perhaps a `TIMESTAMP(0)` data type?

Comment: I have added the Z (was missing because this is just an example) and posted the structure of the table and the relative generated code.

Comment: Well, it might be a bug, but I don't see the reason in the posted code yet. If it's a bug, please report one here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose, and ideally, if possible, provide an MCVE to help reproduce the problem. Template here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve